# Microsoft Teams - How to disable keyboard shortcuts

Tags: bash, intellij-idea, microsoft-teams

In Microsoft-Teams, when I request and gain control, I intend to control a remote application, say my coworker's IntelliJ or bash.

Using keyboard shortcuts - e.g. `<Ctrl>+N` for opening a file, or `<TAB>` to auto-complete - does not work as expected, because it's Microsoft-Teams that *consumes* the command, not the intended target application.

Question: Is it possible to prevent Microsoft-Teams Desktop-Application from *stealing* these commands?

--

I googled [that](https://businesstechplanet.com/how-to-disable-microsoft-teams-keyboard-shortcuts/) instruction, but applying it had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

FOUND PARTIAL SOLUTION

Check this out : https://businesstechplanet.com/how-to-disable-microsoft-teams-keyboard-shortcuts/

By accessing the registry editor you can **disable all shortcuts** on teams (I tend to not use them anyway)

Steps from the page (all props to Saajid Gangat)

> First, you need to open the “Start” menu.
>
> From there, find and open the “Registry Editor.”
>
> Input the following in the editor.
> “Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Teams”
>
> Once the “Teams” registry panel is open, simply right-click and click
> on “New.”
>
> Set the key “DWORD (32 bit) value”.
>
> Name the value “NoKeyShorts.”
>
> Double click on the newly created key and change “Value data” to 1.
>
> Press “OK.”
>
> Finally, restart your computer.

Comment: What makes this a "partial" solution?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an option to disable the shortcuts in teams, but feel free to upvote [this](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/a975b2f3-0c5a-ec11-a819-6045bd7907c5) Microsoft feedback post. The only workaround I found was a reply from a Microsoft employee on [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/turn-off-teams-ctrlshiftc-call-shortcut-i-keep/89b35005-745c-4123-aee9-88d721e2bb0d) post to use a tool like [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) to remap the shortcuts that you want to use to free them although I don't know if by doing this you will be able to use the freed shortcuts remotely or if Teams will still consume the action but just ignore it.

(I would have answered as a comment since this is not really a solution but I can't comment because of my low reputation)

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS, I also had the problem that while in other applications, some keyboard shortcuts would start something in Microsoft Teams. I managed to turn that off by following these steps:

- Open System Preferences
- Go to Privacy and Security, then Accessibility
- Disallow Microsoft Teams